# When high frequency current goes through a superconductor, does it still radiate off like it would with copper?

Tags: current, high-frequency, skin-effect, superconductors

I've been thinking about the skin effect and that got me thinking: When high frequency current goes through a superconductor, does it still radiate off like it would with copper?

Comment: What have you found so far in your search?

Comment: Well, what causes radiation?

Comment: Yes. There are radiations due to the AC current in the conductor, and thermal radiations due to the resistance of the conductor, which are lower for supraconductors than copper.

Comment: Superconductors have zero resistance. That's what makes them superconductors.

Comment: If the current is not DC, then I think some radiation would come off of the conductor due to a time varying magnetic field. In other words, a superconducting antenna would still be an antenna.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Regardless of the resistance in a conductor, when a time varying current flows, it gives rise to a time varying magnetic field outside the conductor. When conditions are right, that time-varying magnetic field will give rise to a transverse electromagnetic wave (TEM).

In other words, an antenna constructed from super-conducting elements would still function as an antenna. The fact that the series resistance is zero does not prevent the antenna from functioning.

Comment: How much would radiate off compared to copper?

Comment: If the current is the same, I think the radiation would be the same.

Comment: It wouldn't be less due to lower resistance?

Comment: I said if the current is the same, the radiation would be the same. The resistance may mean that the copper radiator requires a slightly higher voltage to achieve the same current.

Comment: what about this? https://www.quora.com/Does-skin-effect-occur-in-superconductors

Comment: Post a new question. If skin effect still occurs, that would imply a non-uniform current density throughout the conductor cross-section. Superconductivity applies only up to some maximum current density. Above that, the super-condcutor has non-zero resistance. If skin effect concentrates the current density into the outer surface of the conductor, it may reach that limit at a lower total current.

Comment: It should maybe be mentioned that the [radiation resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_resistance) effect means a superconducting antenna would present a nonzero resistance to the rest of the circuit, even while still superconducting, because some of the energy of the current in the antenna would be transferred to the generated EM waves.

Comment: It also means superconductors still have inductance (no point to superconducting coils if it didnt)